# How to process data in parallel with an exe file by using Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, wine

I am studying Hadoop.

I want to process data in parallel with an exe file by using Hadoop.

I tried to call an exe file in the Mapper class, but the following error occurred.

■Error message:

```
wine: '/home' is not owned by you, refusing to create a configuration directory there
```

■My environment:

OS: CentOS 7 (VMWare)

Hadoop 2.9.2（pseudo-distributed）

java openjdk 1.8.0_191

■Method 1 : Specify "WINEPREFIX"

I set WINEPREFIX in the java file at run time. And used the code below.

```
ProcessBuilder pb_ex = new ProcessBuilder( "export", "WINEPREFIX=/user/(username)/wine_env" ); // the directory /user/(username)/wine_env is exists.
Process process_ex = pb_ex.start();
process_ex.waitFor();
```

However, the following error occurred.

```
Error: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "export": error=2, No such file or directory
```

■Method 2 : “chown” for "/home"

I executed the jar file after executing the following code in the terminal.

```
bin/hdfs dfs -chown (username) /home
or
bin/hdfs dfs -chown -R (username) /home
```

Same error occurred as the first error (wine: '/home' is not owned by you, refusing to create a configuration directory there).

■Method 3 : Changing access authority

The access authority of "./home" on HDFS was changed from 1 to 2.

1 : drwxr-xr-x

2 : drwxrwxrwx

Same error occurred as the first error (wine: '/home' is not owned by you, refusing to create a configuration directory there).

■Source code:

I used source code from the official page’s tutorial. (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html)

I changed the "map" function of TokenizerMapper class as follows.

※"convertInputStreamToString()" is function that converts a Stream value to a String value.

※"fileName" already acquired.

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
  while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
    word.set(itr.nextToken());
    context.write(word, one);
  }
  // from here
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( "./testHello.exe", fileName );
  Process process = pb.start();
  int ret = process.waitFor();
  InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
  InputStream es = process.getErrorStream();
  String theString1 = convertInputStreamToString(is);
  String theString2 = convertInputStreamToString(es);
  Text word2 = new Text( ret + " " + cmd + " ," + theString1 + " ," + theString2);
  IntWritable one2 = new IntWritable(1);
  context.write(word2, one2);   // Confirm error message
}
```

■Expected results:

ret=0

■Actual results:

ret=1

theString2=wine: '/home' is not owned by you, refusing to create a configuration directory there

Does anyone have any ideas about other things I can try?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Getting desperate here.

Comment: It seems there is some confusion with local file system vs HDFS. Do you run hadoop in local or in cluster mode? What is the user name used to run hadoop daemons? Does it help to set HOME env variable to the correct home directory in the process builder?

Comment: >gudok Thank you for your comment. 1. I used Hadoop in cluster mode(pseudo-distribution) by using “start-dfs.sh” and “start-yarn.sh”. 2. User name is “centos”. I got it by using “ProcessBuilder(“whoami”).start();” in “map” function. 3. I used “ProcessBuilder(“export”, “HOME=…”).start();”. The flowing error occurred “Error: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "export": …” in “map” function. How do I set HOME?

Comment: >Ben Watson Thank you for your comment. My understanding is that MapReduce (especially Mapper) works for parallel processing. Since aggregation(Reducer) is not necessary this time, I thought to use only Mapper. And I must use an exe file. Should I look for methods other than Hadoop?